# Recommended frameworks for single-page web apps in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, node.js, frameworks, singlepage

I am looking for Node.JS based frameworks dedicated to creating single-page web apps, such as backbone.io - but more complete, i.e. with bindings for a JavaScript GUI/Widget toolkit such as qooxdoo. 
So that the GUI can be specified in server-side code and is automatically "streamed" to the client using the default route "/".

To clarify, I am not interested in the usual XHTML-based web design stuff, I just need a way to create a server-side application that serves a GUI (multiple tabbed treeviews) to the client in the form a single-page application.

Preferably, all of this could be specified on the server-side, rather than by duplicating code in client-side JavaScript/HTML.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need one. For serious, use some backend libraries for node and write the client side code by hand. Also why you sock puppet

Comment: the idea is to dynamically stream the GUI to the client rather than include the static JS code, part of this is also to obfuscate the GUI code.

Comment: We both know obfuscating the GUI code has zero value.

Answer (score 0):

The aforementioned Qooxdoo has a server edition for node.js.

**It is available here:** http://qooxdoo.org/